# How to set context on an Angular [cdkPortalOutlet]

Tags: angular, angular-material2

The [Portal](https://material.angular.io/cdk/portal/overview) module in Angular Material (CDK) is a very powerful way to render dynamic content into a 'PortalOutlet'.

A `Portal<T>` can be a TemplateRef where `T` is the type of the context data.

```
<ng-template cdkPortal let-data>
    <p>Portal contents {{ data | json }}</p>
</ng-template>
```

You get a reference to it with `@ViewChild`

```
@ViewChild(CdkPortal) myPortalRef: CdkPortal;
```

You can display a portal in a `cdkPortalOutlet`

```
Content gets inserted here: 
<ng-template [cdkPortalOutlet]="myPortalRef"></ng-template>
```

This will insert the portal contents into the outlet.

But there are two big missing features with the provided directives.

```
1) no way to set the actual context object on the outlet using the directive
2) no way to set the context object on the portal itself
```

You can manually create an portal and provide a context, or attach a Portal to a PortalOutlet programatically with a context but I want to do it more declaratively.

The similar (and more commonly used) [`[NgTemplateOutlet]`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet) does provide a property for `[ngTemplateOutletContext]`.

What's the best way to set context on a CdkPortal? Should I extend the directives myself, or try to pass through my data with a service? I thought the whole point of this module was to make things super easy.

[Angular source](https://github.com/angular/material2/tree/47a8f764d1713fb6b7ce84bffc0a12a9525c4a42/src/cdk/portal)

See also: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/6310

Answer (score 8):

I have hit the same questioning, and ended up thinking we are actually taking this from the wrong angle!

Injecting a context only makes sense if we have a **template** to project. In that case, the variables are added to the template environment and they can be bound to component properties in the template code:

```html
<ng-template #user_details let-user>
  <qtl-manage-user-panel [user]="user"></qtl-manage-user-panel>
</ng-template>
```

But without a `ng-template` (i.e. the `Portal` case), that would feel weird. The target component would have out-of-the-box context, without a `let` directive. And what variables should it be bound to?

So, getting back to our case of projecting an actual component into the Portal: how to pass context? The best answer is **Injection** I think.

The context will be passed through a custom Injector to the component's constructor when it's built. All it takes is creating custom injection tokens:

```js
export const MY_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<TTT>('xxx');
```

Then, when creating the `ComponentPortal`, we give a custom injector:

```js
const injector =
Injector.create({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: MY_TOKEN,
      useValue: /* Here, the context variable */,
    },
  ]});

const cPortal = new ComponentPortal(ComponentClass, null, injector);
```

That way, the context variable will be injected in the `ComponentClass` constructor, and can be accessed through:

```js
constructor(
    @Inject(MY_TOKEN) public context: CCC,
  ) { ... }
```

And now `context` can be used in the component class or template.

A little late to the party, but I hope it can help people ending up on this question in the future.

Comment: Your answer is cool and taught me some things, but I'm afraid it misses the point of OP's question. 
The OP wants to **decalratively** use a `TemplatePortal`, not a `ComponentPortal` by using the `[cdkPortal]` directive on an `ng-template`. So his use case has **both** a template, **and** a `Portal`. The `TemplatePortal` [API](https://v9.material.angular.io/cdk/portal/api#CdkPortal) has no injector, and instead has an explicit `context` property which they would like to set as declartively as possible.

Comment: @Quortex - you are the man!!! I am building a design system Angular library for my company and have to build a lot of components that can take other comps & templates & instead of going full monty with browser APIs I decided to use Angular Material  CDK. Of course the first stumbling block was how to dynamically pass ng-template to directive that is popover trigger initialising PortalComponent to display in CDK Overlay. I need to do more reading but your answer put me on the right track and I ave it working now. Only I understand half of it ;-D. I wish the ng CDK docs were easier to digest.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can assign the context directly to the portal but I haven't tested this. It has to be assigned before the outlet uses the portal and that might be tricky.

```
@ViewChild(CdkPortal) myPortalRef: CdkPortal;  

public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.myPortalRef.context = {...}; // your context data
}
```

I think the issue here is that the context is attached to the portal instead of being independant. So you can't use the same portal to render in two different outlets with two different contexts.

Also, have you tried using `cdkPortalOutlet` with the micro-syntax parser in Angular to see if it works?

```
<ng-template *cdkPortalOutlet="myPortalRef; context: contextExp"></ng-template>
```

From what I can tell the `ng-template` methods for the portals isn't used in the library. Everything with portals is done as services, and the template variant appears to have been an add on feature for the community but it wasn't fully vetted.

Comment: I was perusing through the sourcecode for portals until much much too late Friday night. There's no mention of `context` at all in `cdkPortalOutlet`. I think to be honest maybe 'context' isn't even what I want for my particular situation. I  need the value to be able to change in a well defined way, and i think 'context' is meant really more as a hack for passing data to a template where there wouldn't be any other way to do so. For me I know exactly what component is in the template so I can inject a service to it. For future reference I'm still looking for a better way with portals to do it

Comment: I still can't even find a single example showing how to use 'context' at all!

Comment: @Simon_Weaver I found it by looking at the source code.

Comment: Suggested solution causes error: `Can't bind to 'cdkPortalOutletContext' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-template'`